# Will Javascript URLs hurt SEO?

Tags: javascript, seo

I'm making a word cloud with the jQuery plugin jQCloud, in which each word in the cloud is associated with a URL.  I want each of those URLs crawled and indexed by Google/Bing.

jQCloud takes a hash specifying the word, rank, and URL.  So if the bots read the JavaScript they will read the URL, but there will be no HREF without the JavaScript being rendered.

Based on Google's SEO documentation, I presume the bots won't index those URLs.  Is this right?  If so, what would be the most SEO-friendly approach to this wordcloud?

Comment: By "JavaScript url", you mean a normal url that's just dynamically generated, yes?

Comment: The URL is generated by Rails.  If you view source, the URL is fully present in the JavaScript code (JavaScript does not generate the URL).  JavaScript creates the HREF tags, though.  Without JavaScript, there are no links.

Answer (score 2):

In short yes.  Search bots are not going to bother parsing your JS because you could not be bothered to provide static accessible content.

Comment: Down vote for the judgmental tone of the answer. There are more recent answers with better information

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "javascript URLs", they are an anti-accessibility feature. Some reading:

1. [Broken Links](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2011/02/09/Hash-Blecch)
2. [Hash, Bang, Wallop.](http://blog.benward.me/post/3231388630)
3. [Breaking the Web with hash-bangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)
4. [Going Postel](http://adactio.com/journal/4346/)

Answer (score 1):

That's why some browsers already implemented HTML5 PushState API, which uses the original URL but has the capability of understanding if it's Ajax or not and enables browser's navigation buttons (back/next).

Give a look at [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) project, a wrapper to help you use the API.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to have your cloud degrade gracefully. For example, you could have a static list of your links created server-side with the page; if JavaScript is enabled, you could replace this list with your prettier cloud.

This has a benefit apart from being more transparent to search engines: people with JavaScript off will be able to see your links and it will improve accessibility.